# How do I transform list of lists into a dataframe where outerlists are columns and innerlist (of each outerlist) are rows

Tags: r

I have a list of list with thousands of measurements. What I want is to transform the list of list into a dataframe where each outerlist is a column and the values of each innerlist are rows. So that `list[[1]][1]]` and `list[[2]][[1]]` are "rbinded" into the same column.

Example list:

```
set.seed(1)
list <- list(list(round(runif(2), 1), round(runif(2), 1), round(runif(2), 1)),
     list(round(runif(2), 1), round(runif(2), 1), round(runif(2), 1)),
     list(round(runif(2), 1), round(runif(2), 1), round(runif(2), 1)))
```

What I want is to transform it to the following dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c(0.3, 0.4, 0.9, 0.7, 0.7, 0.4),
                col2 = c(0.6, 0.9, 0.6, 0.1, 0.8, 0.5),
                col3 = c(0.2, 0.9, 0.2, 0.2, 0.7, 1))
```

Is there a way to this automatically? Answers in baseR are very much appreciated.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: In practice, it is not recommended to name objects after function names. Also, using lists of lists is non optimal to store data, it's very lengthy, doesn't run quickly in loops and is hard to interprete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution in `base R`:

```r
do.call("rbind", lapply(list, \(x) setNames(data.frame(x),
  paste0("col", 1:length(x)))))

#>   col1 col2 col3
#> 1  0.3  0.6  0.2
#> 2  0.4  0.9  0.9
#> 3  0.9  0.6  0.2
#> 4  0.7  0.1  0.2
#> 5  0.7  0.8  0.7
#> 6  0.4  0.5  1.0
```

---

Another possible solution, using `tidyverse`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

map_dfr(list, ~ data.frame(.x) %>% set_names(str_c("col", 1:length(.x))))

#>   col1 col2 col3
#> 1  0.3  0.6  0.2
#> 2  0.4  0.9  0.9
#> 3  0.9  0.6  0.2
#> 4  0.7  0.1  0.2
#> 5  0.7  0.8  0.7
#> 6  0.4  0.5  1.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't name your list list, in my code lst

```
sapply(
  1:length(lst),
  function(i){
    sapply(lst,"[[",i)
  }
)

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  0.3  0.6  0.2
[2,]  0.4  0.9  0.9
[3,]  0.9  0.6  0.2
[4,]  0.7  0.1  0.2
[5,]  0.7  0.8  0.7
[6,]  0.4  0.5  1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lapply(lst, data.table::transpose) |> 
  unlist() |> 
  matrix(ncol = lengths(lst)[[1]], byrow = TRUE)

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  0.3  0.6  0.2
[2,]  0.4  0.9  0.9
[3,]  0.9  0.6  0.2
[4,]  0.7  0.1  0.2
[5,]  0.7  0.8  0.7
[6,]  0.4  0.5  1.0
```

Comment: add `|> as.data.frame()` to end up with a `data.frame`.